# How to print JSON data mysql?

Tags: mysql, json

I'm just learning MySQL and PHP. I have a problem with echo JSON from MySQL.
Anyone, please help me fix. Thank you so much

I have 2 table below. table channel and channel detail

> ```
> Table 1: channel
> id|name
> 1 |channel 1
> 2 | channel 2
>
> Table 2: detail
> id| detail | cid (get from id table 1)
> 1 | detail 1
> 2 | detail 2
> ```

I try echo JSON like this but output wrong I want
This my code PHP and select MySQL

```
 $query="SELECT * FROM channel, detail WHERE channel.id=detail.cid";
$resouter = mysql_query($query);
$set = array();
$total_records = mysql_num_rows($resouter);
if($total_records >= 1){ 
  while ($link = mysql_fetch_array($resouter, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
    $set['channels'][] = $link;
  }
}

 echo $val= str_replace('\\/', '/', json_encode($set));
```

I want output like that

```
{

"data": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "channel 1",
        "chanels": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "channel.cid": 1,
                "title": "detail 1"
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "channel.cid": 1,
                "title": "detail 2"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "title": "channel 2",
        "chanels": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "channel.cid": 1,
                "title": "detail 1"
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "channel.cid": 1,
                "title": "detail 2"
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

Comment: Some one suggestion